# What is the purpose of the genealogy of Genesis 4:17-22?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit, genealogy

What is the purpose of the genealogy of [Genesis 4:17–22](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8168#showrashi=true&v=17)?

Answer (score 1):

[Gersonides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) addresses this question in his commentary to those verses:

> הנה זה הוא ביאור זה הסיפור ובא בתורה ללמדנו מי היו הממציאים אלו המלאכות כדי שתתישב יותר אמונת החדוש בנפשנו כמו שקדם
>
> Behold, this is the explanation. And it comes in the Torah to teach us who the progenitors of these crafts were, in order to settle more within us the belief in creation [as mentioned] earlier.

(See [this related answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/32007/why-does-the-torah-give-us-exact-dates-for-the-flood/95727#95727) for more examples of Gersonides explaining that details in biblical stories are provided in order to strengthen readers’ belief in the veracity of the stories.)

> ולפי שאלו התולדות כבר נמחו כולם ואין תועלת בזכירתם להודיע איך הסתעפו האומות המתחלפות ללשונותם מאב אחד קצר בזכירתם ולא זכר בני כמה שנים היו כשהולידו וכמה חיו והאריך בלמך יותר מכלם לספר שמות נשותיו לפי שזרעו היו הממציאים הרבה מהמלאכות אשר זכר שהומצאו בזה הסיפור והנה ספר שאחות תובל קין היא נעמה לפי שכבר זכר שנשאה נח ונשאר ממנה זרע כמו שאמרו בבראשית רבה ולולי זה לא אדע טעם לזה
>
> And because these descendants have already been entirely eradicated and there is no benefit in mentioning them to make known how the nations of different tongues branched out from one father, [the Torah] exercised brevity in mentioning them and did not mention how old they were when they bore children or how long they lived. And [the Torah] elaborated about Lamech more than all of them — telling the names of his wives — because his descendants were the progenitors of many of the crafts that are mentioned as originating in this narrative. And [the Torah] tells that the sister of Tubal Cain was Na'amah, because it was already mentioned that Noah married her and left progeny from her as is stated in [Genesis Rabbah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_Rabbah). And barring this I don't know a reason for this.